# Is every cell competent?

Tags: cell-biology, competent-cells

I would like to know if every cell is competent or if there are any cells that are not competent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are asking about *E.coli* cells being made competent for transformation using plasmid DNA, an answer is cached [here](http://scholar.googleusercontent.com/scholar?q=cache%3atBaJCHM2y-MJ%3ascholar.google.com/&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) from this source:

> Hanahan, D. & Bloom, F.R. (1996). Mechanisms of DNA transformation. In F.C. Neidhardt (ed.). Escherichia coli and Salmonella : Cellular and Molecular Biology. (pp. 2449-2459). Washington D.C., United States: ASM Press.

The source (and it is perhaps worth emphasising that Hanahan is/was a transformation guru) states that treatment with divalent cations can achieve 10% of cells rendered competent, whereas treatment for electroporation can achieve transfer into 95% of cells.

This information was, of course, published in 1996 so it is conceivable that advances have been made in the case of the former method.